# Any online tools for converting jQuery into good old fashion Javascript online?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fiddling around with various video resizing methods similar to Zurbs [flex video](http://www.zurb.com/word/responsive-video) and found the easiest option, for me, on css-tricks site [here](http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php), code is as follows (in jQuery):

```
        var $allVideos = $("iframe[src^='http://player.vimeo.com'], iframe[src^='http://www.youtube.com']"),
          $fluidEl = $(".content");
        $allVideos.each(function() {
          $(this).data('aspectRatio', this.height / this.width)
          .removeAttr('height').removeAttr('width');
        });
        $(window).resize(function() {
          var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();
          $allVideos.each(function() {
            var $el = $(this);
            $el.width(newWidth).height(newWidth * $el.data('aspectRatio'));
          });
        }).resize();
```

jQuery API's are great an all, but, there is no other jQuery being used in this particular instance, so I find it hard to justify loading an entire jQuery library over a few lines of code... Are there any tools online for converting jQuery to 'old school' js? As I've ran into this issue on more than one occasion, I'm just starting to dig into learning Javascript as it seems to be require more as a prerequisite these days. So even a few reference sites that kinda dip into the subject would be a huge help.

Comment: You can, but why? If you load jQuery from a CDN, your users will most likely have a cached copy already there.

Comment: Valid point. Not quite what I'm looking for, but valid nonetheless. But, it is still an unnecessary HTTP request and I've read in numerous places about slighter faster load times with plain jane vanilla javascript. I'm sure I'm just being nit-picky and doubt if there is too large of a difference in load times either way, but am still hoping to not have to load an unnecessary library for such a short snippet of code.

Comment: Which browsers do you have to support?

Comment: I'm targeting modern browsers and IE8+

Comment: more specifically it is currently compatible with these this and newer: IE 8+, Firefox 4+, Safari 5+, Opera, Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about any conversion tool.
But if you're interested in learning jquery, here you have a link that will help.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/15-resources-to-get-you-started-with-jquery-from-scratch/

Comment: Thank you kindly, I'll definitely be reading into these resources.